# Run apk on android x86 emulator but install on ARM smartphone

Tags: android, android-emulator, ionic-framework, apk

The android x86 emulator runs much faster on a Windows PC. I would like to use the x86 emulator. However, my apk is to be built and run on a smartphone running a ARM processor. Do I need to do special things to get the apk working on both the x86 emulator and ARM phone?

The reason I asked is that I was able to run successfully on x86 emulator but the apk file could not be installed on my phone. I was using ionic to build the apk with a simple command `ionic build android`

Comment: Not unless you require native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't any compatibility problem, I already ran my app both on x86 and ARM architecture.
Have you tried to remove it before installing it, if it was already on your phone ?
What error did you get when you tried to install it ?